# Why does Vue 3 not recognize my Vuex store module?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm very new to Vuex and I'm having trouble getting Vue 3 to recognize my store module:

**Store:**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { UserModule } from "./User";

export default createStore({
  state: {},

  mutations: {},

  actions: {},

  modules: {
    User: UserModule,
  }
});
```

**User:**

```
export const UserModule = {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    user: null,
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state: any, user: any) {
      state.user = user;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    setUser({commit}: any, user: any) {
      commit('SET_USER', user);
    }
  },
  modules: {}
}
```

**Router:**

```
import store from "../store";

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const user: any = store.state.User.user;
}
```

[image: Typescript linting error]

It works if I use state directly from the store, but, I'd like to use it from modules.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try removing the unnecessary properties from your store: `state`, `mutations` and `actions`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not fix the error.

Comment: You are using typescript, but haven't defined any types/interfaces here. Maybe this can help: https://dev.to/shubhadip/vue-3-vuex-4-modules-typescript-2i2o

Comment: @oemera I'm looking into that and I've encountered different problems now, but either way it seems a lot more complicated than it should be to solve something like this.

Mostly I'm saying that because everything was working perfectly fine up until I switched to using the module instead of the state in the index.js of store